# Access web service via curl PHP or some thing similar

Tags: php, web-services, curl, php-curl

I have this type of API code and how can I send request to access this web service in php? can I use curl ? Please help me

Sandbox URL :
http://api.lankagate.gov.lk:8280/GetOnGoingVehicleNoDMT/1.0
Method POST

Parameter Name - vehicleCategory
Options - 1 , 4

Success Response Code: 200

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <soap:Body>
 <GetOnGoingVehicleNoResponse
xmlns="http://schemas.conversesolutions.com/xsd/dmticta/v1">
 <return>
 <ResponseMessage xsi:nil="true" />
 <ErrorCode xsi:nil="true" />
 <OngoingVehicleNo>CAW-2186</OngoingVehicleNo>
 </return>
 </GetOnGoingVehicleNoResponse>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

Sample

Call URL : http://api.lankagate.gov.lk:8280/Transliteration/1.0/
Message body :
<soapenv:Envelope
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:v1="http://schemas.conversesolutions.com/xsd/dmticta/v1">
 <soapenv:Header/>
 <soapenv:Body>
 <v1:GetOnGoingVehicleNo>
 <v1:vehicleCategory>1</v1:vehicleCategory>
 </v1:GetOnGoingVehicleNo>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Notes Set request header as
Authorization: Bearer Access Token

I have tried and this is my code

```
function get_exam_mode_of_study() {
        $xml_data = '<soapenv:Envelope
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:v1="http://schemas.conversesolutions.com/xsd/dmticta/v1">
 <soapenv:Header/>
 <soapenv:Body>
 <v1:GetOnGoingVehicleNo>
 <v1:vehicleCategory>1</v1:vehicleCategory>
 </v1:GetOnGoingVehicleNo>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>';
        $URL = "http://api.lankagate.gov.lk:8280/GetOnGoingVehicleNoDMT/1.0";
        $ch = curl_init($URL);
//        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MUTE, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "$xml_data");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        print_r($output);
        exit;
        curl_close($ch);
//        }
    }
```

and it gives following error

```
<ams:fault xmlns:ams="http://wso2.org/apimanager/security"><ams:code>900902</ams:code><ams:message>Missing Credentials</ams:message><ams:description>Required OAuth credentials not provided. Make sure your API invocation call has a header: "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN"</ams:description></ams:fault>
```

Comment: _"can I use curl?"_ - Why don't you give it a shot and try? This question lacks any code to show us that you've made any attempt to solve this yourself. If you've tried something, show us what you've tried, example of the expected output and what you're actually getting. If you _haven't_ tried anything, you need to do that before posting. We can help you with your _existing_ code, but we won't write it for you. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-t

Comment: @MagnusEriksson updated

Comment: Like the message says, you're not adding the auth header. In your curl call, try changing `array('Content-Type: text/xml')` to `array('Content-Type: text/xml', 'Authorization: Bearer your-access-token-here')`  for the `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` option.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the Authorization header

CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER for curl_setopt() takes an array with each header as an element.

You can use below $header array.

```
$header = array();
$header[] = 'Content-length: 0';
$header[] = 'Content-type: application/json';
$header[] = 'Authorization: Bearer OAuthAccess_TokenThatIReceived';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$header);
```